# Shopify proxy is not working with manifest.json (shopify and laravel)

Tags: laravel, shopify

I'm a beginner in Shopify and trouble with Shopify proxy

**Front Store:** `https://bhavin.myshopify.com`

**App Store:** `https://myapp.ngrok.io` (Laravel)

I want to add two files (custom js and manifest.json) in my front store.

Install and authentication is working fine

I'm adding `manifest.json` something like that

```
var link    =   document.createElement('link');
link.rel    =   'manifest';
link.href   =   'https://myapp.ngrok.io/manifest.json';
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

**1. Without proxy**

`manifest.json` file added properly but throw error something like that

`Access to resource at 'https://myapp.ngrok.io/manifest.json' from origin 'https://bhavin.myshopify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

**2. With Proxy**

```
Subpath prefix: apps
Subpath:        cnv
Proxy URL:      https://myapp.ngrok.io/proxy
```

Now my `manifest.json` file path is `https://bhavincb.myshopify.io/apps/cnv/manifest.json`

Url is working fine if I'm logged in the admin panel 
If I open that URL when I'm not logged in then it returns 
`This page isn’t working with HTTP ERROR 401`

In my front store while load manifest file it is showing something like that (when logged in)

```
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

There is not any error in `manifest.json`

[image]

I'm using  [Laravel Shopify](https://github.com/ohmybrew/laravel-shopify) package

As of I know, I guess I'm doing something wrong with a proxy configuration.

Does anyone have a solution?

**Any help will appreciate**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved to issue my self (ref. 2. With Proxy)

The issue with my store actually I'm using **free trial** and in **free trial** you can't disable **password protection**

If your **password protection** is enabled and you are trying to access proxy URL without logged in, in that case, Shopify won't allow accessing.

After purchase plan, it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

In Fact the problem is not the password of Shopify demo.
The problem is that when the browser send the request for manifest the request need to send the cookies of shopify auth or it will be redirected to password screen.

So the solution is to add "use-credential" like this in your html :

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/app.webmanifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" />
```

(See doc here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

Answer (score -1):

The better recipe to follow might be this. One, you use your App to access the assets of the shop theme, and upload your **manifest.json** text file as an asset. That means it is accessible in Liquid, in the theme, and the shop can therefore render it and make it useful.

Second, use your App to install **custom.js** as a ScriptTag asset. That is the usual way to accomplish running your own JS.

The App Proxy is not really meant for use the way you are using it.

Comment: if admin change the theme then my code is not working I guess

Comment: `izooto.com` is using a proxy to add a manifest.json file
E.g.
`https://www.bajaao.com/apps/izooto/5b5a6ec35f3a0a7f8789184dfa7c291caf01b92f/manifest.json`

Comment: Also, **Pushowl.com** is using their own URL to add a manifest file.


`https://api.pushowl.com/manifest.json`

is there any way that I can add manifest file something like that

Comment: You are not understanding the pattern it seems. You use JS to call your server. Your server validates the call. You return data. You can return JSON as I said you could. As far as pushowl goes... sure.. call your own endpoint. You have no good security for that, but you might not care.